# Role of Self-hosting in WCF Service

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services

Can someone help me in understanding the role of self-hosting in WCF?
Is this only for testing and development purpose? or can this also be useful any sort of real time application??

Why do we actually need service if we self-host it and limit it to a application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WCF can be self hosted as a windows service (like what SPereyaslov suggested) or as an IIS service. The reason to host the WCF program (or any program) as windows service is so that the program starts and runs no matter who is logged on. In fact, if you have your program running as a windows service, the service can restart automatically if the server is restarted. That's the advantage.

Your question: Why do we need to make code as service when we have both client and service on the same machine? You don't need it to run as a service if both the client and web service are on the same machine. You could run compile and run the WCF program as an executable, but in a normal commmercial environment, you wouldn't have the WCF program and client on the same machine.

Answer (score 0):

For example, you can host WCF service inside Windows Service. I think this case more natural if you need only tcp binding without http binding

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just a basic question. Why do we need to make code as service when we have both client and service on the same machine?